# Need help identifying an integrated circuit

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, dip, rca

Pulled from a large tube TV, this one is a real head scratcher. I think it's an RCA chip but all RCA chips I've see use a different part naming scheme (for example `CAxxxx`).

It's like the parts RCA A23 346-1, and the RCA A23 1101-01 but there's no record (I can find) that lists RCA making parts of this series.

Can anybody identify the IC from the picture below?

[image]

Comment: It's over 20 years old (you can tell from the 9245 date code -- 45th week of 1992). Good luck.

Comment: Looks like a custom ASIC, so I'm sorry to say it but you're probably SOL

Comment: Better to start with the TV model number and search for a manual or schematic. Using that you can locate it by Part ID and a least see the function and hopefully a part number.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Sunergia](http://sunergia.net/es/4364/a23-837-1), A23-837-1 cross references to RCA part #176226. [Encompass](https://lg.encompass.com/item/341858/RCA/176226/Ic) identifies it as [TA7630P](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/toshiba/3469.pdf), a DC controlled dual volume, balance, bass, treble audio IC. This matches your chip's package and country of origin.

[image]

Comment: That's quite a piece of detective work.